# Pixkup not working on one string on one pickup

Tags: electric-guitar

Here's a puzzler.  On my American Standard Strat the G string is not picked up on the middle pickup but is picked up on the bridge and neck pickups. When I play the G string on the middle pickup it's just like playing it  unamplified.  Try to figure that one out!

Comment: But the other strings all sound fine on the middle pickup?

Comment: Do the fender pickups have 6 posts in the single coil or a single metal bar?  It could be that the post for the g string is not set correctly, or defective/damaged.

Comment: @ggcg my strat has single posts for each string. Would touching the string to the post to see if it makes noise be a good test?

Comment: As far as I know, Strat pups have fixed poles. My first action would be to tap each pole in turn with a small screwdriver. If the offending pole reacts, it won't be that. I guess it's not the string, as it works on the other pups? What happens on positions 2 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

You've presented us with a puzzler. It's only a guess on my part, but it sounds to me like the magnetic pole on that string has lost it's charge. You could test this by touching a common nail (iron) to that pole to see if it's attracted. If that proves to be the case, you may be able to remove the pole piece and recharge it magnetically by stroking it with another strong magnet. If you're not very skilled this way, then I suggest you taking it in for repair by a qualified technician. I wish you luck.